# Add Google Sheets Conditionally Formatting Custom Formula rule to highlight cells that end in 0

Tags: google-sheets, math, conditional-formatting

I have a table of numbers (B2:DG111)

I want to highlight the cells with values that end in 0

I tried to adjust one of the examples from this [article](https://softwareaccountant.com/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-custom-formula/) but it's not right yet.

Currently I've selected the range and added this Format Rule

```
=COUNTIF(B2:DG111,mod(CN2,10)) = 0
```

This didn't work, also tried to achieve "not ends with" using regex (highlight if ends 1-9)

[image: rule 2 (regex)]

[image: cells]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within conditional formatting, the custom formula would be:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2),"0$")
```

[image]

Comment: Oooh nice ! Thanks  Can there be more than one answer? Accepting in 
~2

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the range, and referenced the first cell (b2) and it worked

```
=mod(B2,10) = 0
```

[image]